# Heroku Free v Hobby package

Tags: heroku

I have an app on the `free` heroku version, and want to upgrade to `hobby`, to avoid the 6 hours of required `dyno sleep` per day.

But I'm confused about the discrepancy between Heroku pricing page, and the info I get from running `heroku apps:info` in my app.

**My app:**

> Add-on: heroku-postgresql (postgresql-angular-8...) 
>   Plan: hobby-dev 
>   Price: free 
>   as: DATABASE

The above implies the app is already on `hobby`... which is confusing because I'm not currently paying anything, and the dyno sleeps 6 hours a day.

**Heroku** ( https://www.heroku.com/pricing )

Per Heroku pricing page, `hobby` is not free (`$7 / dyno / month`). And does not need to sleep.

I'd like to upgrade to the cheapest paid version that doesn't require `dyno sleep` and am confused.

Has anyone dealt with this and can clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database in on the hobby-dev plan which has a row limit of 10,000 rows but your web server (dyno) is probably on the free plan. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans) for more details.